# HIDictionaryWindowShow usage

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to pop up a dictionary lookup in a Mac app using [HIDictionaryWindowShow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/DictionaryServicesRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/HIDictionaryWindowShow). But it doesn't seem to be available; I just get a compile error about "use of undeclared identifier." The other two methods in that documentation, DCSGetTermRangeInString and DCSCopyTextDefinition, will autocomplete for me.

Has HIDictionaryWindowShow been removed, or am I missing something? I've already imported CoreServices and made sure to link it in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As the Dictionary Services documentation states (at the top)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/DictionaryServicesRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/HIDictionaryWindowShow):

> There are three functions described in this reference. Two of them are
>   defined in the Core Services framework; the third is defined in the
>   Carbon framework.

You need to import the Carbon framework to pick up `HIDictionaryWindowShow`.

Comment: Had to be something like that.